# Does "using" statement always dispose the object?

Tags: c#, dispose, using, using-statement

Does the `using` statement always dispose the object, even if there is a return or an exception is thrown inside it? I.E.:

```
using (var myClassInstance = new MyClass())
{
    // ...
    return;
}
```

or

```
using (var myClassInstance = new MyClass())
{
    // ...
    throw new UnexplainedAndAnnoyingException();
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, that's the whole point.  It compiles down to:

```
SomeDisposableType obj = new SomeDisposableType();
try
{
    // use obj
}
finally
{
    if (obj != null) 
        ((IDisposable)obj).Dispose();
}
```

Be careful about your terminology here; the object itself is not deallocated.  The `Dispose()` method is called and, typically, unmanaged resources are released.

Comment: There are some cases that `finally` block will not execute as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 16):

No it doesn't.

But that's not the *fault* of `using` statement though. It's because how the `finally` blocks are handled by CLR. There ARE some cases that `finally` blocks will not execute. If you have an unhandled exception and if the CLR *thinks* that executing more code will lead to more errors, it will not execute `Dispose` method (because it will not execute the `finally` block which `Dispose` method is compiled down to..). Therefore, be very careful and don't put your life into the execution of `Dispose` method.

The other cases which can cause `Dispose` method not being executed can be listed as:

- [Environment.FailFast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_1)
- `OutOfMemoryException`and `StackOverflowException`
- Killing the process
- Power loss

Comment: `Power loss` ... really ?

Comment: Really. Electrical power won't wait for one's badly implemented `Dispose` method to finish keeping the persistence layer in a good state for example.

Comment: @malat [Yes. Power loss.](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/My-Tales) :)

Answer (score 11):

If the object implements IDisposable, it will be called.

From using Statement (C# Reference) by MSDN

> Defines a scope, outside of which an object or objects will be
>   disposed.
>
> The using statement allows the programmer to specify when objects that
>   use resources should release them. The object provided to the using
>   statement must implement the IDisposable interface. This interface
>   provides the Dispose method, which should release the object's
>   resources.