# How to avoid my HttpClient opening multiple connections for single instance of the client?

Tags: c#, singleton, httprequest, httpclient

Based on [this article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) I decided to create single instance for my `HttpClient` in my project, where are sent two requests to my **WebAPI** from its **consumer**. Also to kill the connection aftrewards I decided to use solution from [this article](http://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html). After sending two requests using the singleton I was receiving this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: This instance has already started
>   one or more requests.

So I decided to use the interface and configuration (similar) from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42236220/8532173). Everything seems to work fine, BUT after running **netstat.exe** I noticed, that for my API consumer are opened two (2) different connection with various port numbers:

[image: netstat.exe]

Note that `[::1]:49153` is my **WebAPI** port, so I assume that `[::1]:57612` and `[::1]:57614` are opened for my **consumer**. Why? If they supposed to use the same client?

Should not it be like in the [first mentioned article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)?

My **HttpClientFactory**:

```
public interface IHttpClientFactory
    {
        HttpClient CreateClient();
    }

    public class HttpClientFactory : IHttpClientFactory
    {
        static AppConfig config = new AppConfig();

        static string baseAddress = config.ConnectionAPI;

        public HttpClient CreateClient()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            SetupClientDefaults(client);
            return client;
        }

        protected virtual void SetupClientDefaults(HttpClient client)
        {
            //client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
        }
    }
```

And my two request sending methods:

```
public async Task<bool> SendPostRequestAsync(string serializedData)
        {
            CallerName = _messageService.GetCallerName();
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

            Console.Write(MessagesInfo[CallerName]);

            try
            {
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Config.ApiPostUri);
                request.Content = new StringContent(serializedData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(MessagesResult[CallerName]); //success status

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Status code: " + response.StatusCode.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Error(e.Message.ToString() + ", " + MessagesError[CallerName]);

                CloseConnection();

                return false;
            }

        }
```

and

```
public async Task<bool> SendGetRequestAsync()
        {
            CallerName = _messageService.GetCallerName();
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

            Console.Write(MessagesInfo[CallerName]);

            try
            {
                response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(Config.ApiGetUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(MessagesResult[CallerName]); //success status

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Status code: " + response.StatusCode.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Error(e.Message.ToString() + ", " + MessagesError[CallerName]);

                CloseConnection();

                return false;
            }
        }
```

Connection is closed with:

```
public void CloseConnection()
        {
            CallerName = _messageService.GetCallerName();

            var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(Config.ConnectionAPI));
            sp.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 1 * 1000;

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(MessagesResult[CallerName]);
        }
```

Comment: You may wish to consider changing `HttpClientFactory` to **store** the `HttpClient` (in a `static Lazy`) so it provides the **same** `HttpClient` rather than spinning up new ones.

Comment: can you update the code which worked for you please? facing the same issue now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `Dispose` of `response`, as per [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/35698). *You may wish to use [`using`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357258/does-using-statement-always-dispose-the-object).*

Additionally (from that link):

> It's expected that the connections stay open. You don't want them to
>   stay open at all? By default connections are kept alive in a
>   connection pool for several minutes in order to avoid the expense of
>   creating and tearing them down for every request.

In other words, connections are pooled for future performance (for a short window of time).

Additionally, your:

```
var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(Config.ConnectionAPI));
sp.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 1 * 1000;
```

should be run **once** at startup, not repeatedly. After doing this, you could thus remove the `CloseConnection` method.

Comment: Regarding `var sp ...` it is called only for `catch` blocks and after proper exec of both requests in the program. Is it disposing the client? ... Ill check in documentation...

Comment: No it is not disposing. Read the docs for `ConnectionLeaseTimeout` to see what it does.